# Black screen when running my app on android studio emulator

Tags: android

```
private int clickedNum;
private boolean clicked;
private MediaPlayer soundEff;

private void stopSound() {
    if (soundEff!=null ) {
        soundEff.stop();
        soundEff.release();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simon);
    clickedNum=-1;
    clicked=false;
    Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.simonActivity_quit_button);
    quitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog quitDialog = new Dialog(SimonActivity.this);
            quitDialog.setTitle("Pause Dialog");
            quitDialog.setContentView((R.layout.dialog_quittomain));
            quitDialog.show();
            Button no = (Button)quitDialog.findViewById(R.id.quitdialog_no_button);
            Button yes = (Button)quitDialog.findViewById(R.id.quitdialog_yes_button);

            no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    quitDialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    quitDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    );

    Button sbtn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.simonbtn1);
    sbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedNum=1;
            clicked=true;
            stopSound();
            soundEff =MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this, R.raw.greensound);
            soundEff.start();

        }
    });

    Button sbtn2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.simonbtn2);
    sbtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedNum=2;
            clicked=true;
            stopSound();
            soundEff =MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this, R.raw.redsound);
            soundEff.start();
        }
    });

    Button sbtn3= (Button)findViewById(R.id.simonbtn3);
    sbtn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedNum=3;
            clicked=true;
            stopSound();
            soundEff =MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this, R.raw.yellowsound);
            soundEff.start();
        }
    });

    Button sbtn4= (Button)findViewById(R.id.simonbtn4);
    sbtn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickedNum=4;
            clicked=true;
            stopSound();
            soundEff =MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this, R.raw.bluesound);
            soundEff.start();
        }
    });

    }



public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int[] arrayplayer = new int[10];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int btnclick = rnd.nextInt(4) + 1;
        final Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simonbtn1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simonbtn2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simonbtn3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simonbtn4);
        boolean flag = true;
        int i;
        int iNew;




    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        array[i]=0;
    }

    i=0;

        while (flag && i < 10) {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                array[i] = btnclick;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nihnas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                iNew=0;
                while(array[iNew]!=0&&iNew<10) {
                    if (array[i] == 1) {
                        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this,R.raw.greensound);
                        performClick(R.drawable.key1c, 300, button1, R.drawable.key1,sound);
                        Log.d("balbla", "hey im here");
                    }

                    if (array[i] == 2) {
                        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this,R.raw.redsound);
                        performClick(R.drawable.key2c, 300, button2, R.drawable.key2,sound);
                        Log.d("balbla", "hey im here");
                    }

                    if (array[i] == 3) {
                        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this,R.raw.yellowsound);
                        performClick(R.drawable.key3c, 300, button3, R.drawable.key3,sound);
                        Log.d("balbla", "hey im here");
                    }
                    if (array[i] == 4) {
                        MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(SimonActivity.this,R.raw.bluesound);
                        performClick(R.drawable.key4c, 300, button4, R.drawable.key4,sound);
                        Log.d("balbla", "hey im here");
                    }
                    iNew=+1;
                }
                btnclick = rnd.nextInt(4) + 1;

                clicked=false;

                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    while (clicked == false) {

                    }

                    clicked = false;
                    arrayplayer[j] = clickedNum;
                    flag = Bodek(arrayplayer[j], array[j]);


                }

            }

        }

}


private boolean Bodek(int numJ, int numI){
    return numJ==numI;
}



private void performClick (int id, int miliS, final Button button, final int oldId, final MediaPlayer mp)
{

    button.setBackgroundResource(id);
    mp.start();
    SystemClock.sleep(miliS);
    button.setBackgroundResource(oldId);
    mp.stop();
}
```

I'm trying to create a 'Simon Says' game for a school project.

I am trying to run this causes black screen on the emulator, every other screen on the app works except for this one, I probably messed up the code but it does not give me an error.

Comment: your infinite loops are locking the ui thread

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the endless loop in your OnStart() which is making the UI thread busy.

```
 while (flag && i < 10) {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                array[i] = btnclick;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"nihnas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                iNew=0;
                while(array[iNew]!=0&&iNew<10) {
```